# R - sequentially replace string using a data frame of strings

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to build a function F that replace a target string 'str'  in a data frame of stings 'df', 
column by column, row by row, according to the column name as the sub-string to be replaced, 
and column value as replacements.
result is a string-vector length 'rownum' of replaced strings 
with 'colnum' replacements for each string as the output.

an example would illustrate it best:

`str <- "Hi, I am name and I am age years old! - said name "`

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('John', 'Richard','Edward'), age =c('10','26','12'))

F(str,df)

"Hi, I am John and I am 10 years old! - said John "

"Hi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! - said Richard "

"Hi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! - said Edward "
```

I have written a function for the job:

```
F <- function(str,df)
{
  x <- str
  for(i in names(df)){
    x <- unname(mapply(gsub,i,df[[i]],x))
  }
  return(x)
}
```

and it seems to work, but I'm under the impression that it is not efficient nor elegant.

1. is there a way to avoid a loop?
2. is mapply a necessity?
3. can F work when 'str' is a text of multiple lines, and not just a
   single line?

thanks for your help

Comment: Actually, it would be a good idea to use word boundaries to match `name` and `age` as whole words.

Comment: If possible, I would just use `str <- "Hi, I am %s and I am %s years old! - said %s "; sprintf(str, df$name, df$age, df$name)`.

Comment: You can programmatically do this with `sprintf(gsub("name|age", "%s", str), df$name, df$age, df$name)`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have added your suggestion as a cw-answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @h3rm4n I never mind. Everything I write down is open source. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe another option, which "hides" the for loop:

```
library(stringi)
f <- function(str, df) 
  apply(df, 1, stri_replace_all, str=str, fixed=names(df), merge=T, vec=F)  
f("Hi, I am name and I am age years old! - said name ", df)
# [1] "Hi, I am John and I am 10 years old! - said John "      
# [2] "Hi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! - said Richard "
# [3] "Hi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! - said Edward "

str <- "Hi, I am name and I am age years old! - said name\n
Hi, I am name and I am age years old! - said name"
f(str, df)
# [1] "Hi, I am John and I am 10 years old! - said John\n\nHi, I am John and I am 10 years old! - said John"            
# [2] "Hi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! - said Richard\n\nHi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! - said Richard"
# [3] "Hi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! - said Edward\n\nHi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! - said Edward"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) is a great solution for this kind of string manipulations via templates. For simple strings/templates i would go with `sprintf` as well. For more complex templates i would definitely use Mustache.

The R-implementation of Mustache is the [whisker](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker)-package

In your case this could be done e.g. via:

```
#install.packages("whisker")
library(whisker)
template <- 
"Hi, I am {{name}} and I am {{age}} years old! - 
said {{name}}"

df <- data.frame(name = c('John', 'Richard','Edward'), age =c('10','26','12'))

out <- apply(df, 1, function(x) whisker.render(template, x))
```

which gives you:

```
[1] "Hi, I am John and I am 10 years old! -\nsaid John"      
[2] "Hi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! -\nsaid Richard"
[3] "Hi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! -\nsaid Edward"
```

The linebreak (`\n`) is present is the output.

You can also use `readLines` to initially read your template instead of hardcoding it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach (as presented by @RomanLustrik in the comments):

```
str <- "Hi, I am %s and I am %s years old! - said %s "
sprintf(str, df$name, df$age, df$name)
```

The result:

```
[1] "Hi, I am John and I am 10 years old! - said John "      
[2] "Hi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! - said Richard "
[3] "Hi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! - said Edward "
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this programmatically (inspired from @RomanLustrik's idea

```
do.call(sprintf, c(cbind(df, name2=df$name), fmt = gsub("name|age", "%s", str)))
#[1] "Hi, I am John and I am 10 years old! - said John "    
#[2] "Hi, I am Richard and I am 26 years old! - said Richard "
#[3] "Hi, I am Edward and I am 12 years old! - said Edward "
```